# Retrive all phone numbers of a contact

Tags: android, cursor, android-contacts

I already saw other similar questions and none worked.
With the code below I was able to get the **default** phone number of a contact but not all of them.

```
Cursor contact = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = " + contactId, null, null);
contact.moveToFirst();

phoneNumberList.add(contact.getString(contact.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER)));
```

Then I tried to create multiple cursors with more details about the phone type and then add them to a list:

```
Cursor contact = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, new String[]{ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER}, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ? AND " + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE + " = " + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_HOME, new String[]{contactID}, null);
```

But unfortunately, it didn't solve anything. Would be thankful if someone helps me with this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to get all phone numbers with their type (home, mobile, main, etc.).

Here's how to do it (the list of phones will be printed to log=:

```
String projection = new String[] { Phone.NUMBER, Phone.TYPE, Phone.LABEL };
String selection = Phone.CONTACT_ID + "=" + contactId;
Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(Phone.CONTENT_URI, projection, selection, null, null); 
while (cur != null && cur.moveToNext()) {
    String number = cur.getString(0);
    int type = cur.getInt(1);        // home / office / personal
    String label = cur.getString(2); // a custom label in case type is "TYPE_CUSTOM"
    String labelStr = Phone.getTypeLabel(getResources(), type, label);

    Log.d(TAG, "got a phone: " + number + " (" + labelStr + ")");
}
if (cur != null) {
    cur.close();
}
```

**DEBUG VERSION**

```
String projection = new String[] { Phone._ID, Phone.CONTACT_ID, Phone.NUMBER, Phone.TYPE, Phone.LABEL };
String selection = Phone.CONTACT_ID + "=" + contactId;
Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(Phone.CONTENT_URI, projection, selection, null, null); 
if (cur != null) {
    DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(cur);
    cur.close();
}
```

Comment: Unfortunetly your code also returns the default phone number of a contact, not all of them.

Comment: (a) are you sure the contact you're testing this with has more then one phone number? (b) are you running the exact code, or did you just copy the query line to your code?

Comment: a)yes I checked it several times and b) I used your exact code. Apparently  `cur.getString(0)` or `Phone.NUMBER` always returns the default phone number in api 14+.

Comment: doesn't make sense, I'm using these apis all over my production app and it's working as expected. make sure the `Phone` class is imported from `ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds`, also I'll add a debug version so we can better understand the results, run it and copy the output from the log here

Comment: I tested with another phone and it worked. Don' know why but there may be a bug with Galaxy S4.